# get all keys of hashes in redis

Tags: redis

Can somebody please give me something about how to get all categories and all users in this example

hmset category:1 name opera description music year 1573

OK

> hmset category:2 name snowsports description sport Tmembers groups

OK

> hmset category:3 name java description language year 1995

OK

> hmset user:1 name jack age 23 country france

OK

> hmset user:2 name john age 25 country Uk

Ok

> hmset user:3 name julia age 27 country england

Answer (score 2):

In that example, you'd have to do:

```
KEYS 'category:*'
KEYS 'user:*'
```

If you need to run this in production, use the [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) command instead of keys. Assuming this is in db 0 on your Redis instance:

```
SCAN 0 match 'category:*'
SCAN 0 match 'user:*'
```

Comment: thanks for your replaying ,and i try  this command                             (SCAN 0 match 'category:*')                                                                     and  the answer was  SCAN 0 match 'category:*'
1) "114688"
2) (empty list or set)                                                                                how to know the number of db ?

Comment: Whichever you're connected to. You can use SELECT (http://redis.io/commands/SELECT) to pick one. the INFO command (http://redis.io/commands/INFO) gives you some information about which are being used for what.

Comment: @Eli please never suggest `KEYS` - it should be considered a debugging command

Comment: @ItamarHaber I'm not suggesting otherwise. My answer above is clear on this.

Comment: The order is misleading - people tend to read the first line and rush away to try it. `KEYS` is evil - it can bring your Redis server to its knees in a blink of an eye so it should be considered as a last resort, if at all. I think that the default redis.conf should rename it to `666-your-immortal-soul` just so we're clear ;)